# Is the intersection of n-1 nef divisors in an n-dimensional algebraic variety guaranteed to be in the Mori cone?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

And is there a reference to which someone could point me for this?

Comment: For ample divisors, this is clear -- the intersection of $n-1$ general elements (passing to a multiple if needed) is a curve, hence in the cone.  Isn't the claim then immediate from continuity of the intersection form?

Comment: @Mark : Yes, it is.

Comment: Great thanks!  Is there a good, pedagogical introduction to this material somewhere?  I'm very new to it.

Comment: You can try sections 1.1 & 1.2 of Lazarsfeld's book.  Both of your questions are basically covered by Example 1.2.5 + a continuity argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mori cone $\overline{NE}(X)$ is the dual of $Nef(X)$. Let $C = D_{1}\cap...\cap D_{n-1}$ be the intersection of $n-1$ nef divisors. Since $Nef(X) = \overline{Amp}(X)$ we can find a sequence of divisors $D_{i,\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon > 0$ such that $D_{i,\epsilon}$ is ample for any $\epsilon >0$, and $D_{i,\epsilon}\rightarrow D_i$ for $\epsilon\mapsto 0$, for any $i = 1,...,n-1$.

Now, $C_{\epsilon} = D_{1,\epsilon}\cap ...\cap D_{n-1,\epsilon}$ is the intersection of $n-1$ ample divisors. Therefore $C_{\epsilon}\in\overline{NE}(X)$ for any $\epsilon >0$, and $C_{\epsilon}\rightarrow C$ for $\epsilon\mapsto 0$. Now, if $D$ is nef, we have $D\cdot C_{\epsilon}\geq 0$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, because $\overline{NE}(X)$ is the dual of $Nef(X)$. This yields $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}D\cdot C_{\epsilon} = D\cdot C \geq 0$. That is $C\in\overline{NE}(X)$.